# What is the difference between "= gcnew" and "+= gcnew"?

Tags: c++-cli

Please consider the following line of code:

```
port->DataReceived += gcnew SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

What difference does the preceding `+` mean when used with the `gcnew` keyword?

Comment: In this code, modified the invocation list of the delegate DataReceived.

Answer (score 4):

The `+=` operator does not apply to the `gcnew` operator but to the `DataReceived` event. You are instantiating a new `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` delegate on the managed heap with the 'gcnew' operator, and you are adding it to the invocation list of the `DataReceived` event with of the `+=` operator.

Comment: Basically correct.  That's what happens when you use `+=` with a delegate.  With an event, the `add` method associated with that event is called, which by convention adds to the invocation list, but doesn't have to.